# Can I run .exe file on Heroku?

Tags: node.js, heroku

I am building a node app that has a function that requires running an .exe file. I am using the .exe because it was the only was I was able to get my my legacy fortran code to compile (through intel visual fortran). Will I be able to get my app to run through heroku, and if so, is there anything I need to do besides the basic deploy?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think Heroku has any windows servers. 
As you have the Heroku CLI to enter into the machine where your app is running you can try using Wine (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wine) to run your exe.